# Explanation of proof about elementary properties of graphs needed.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've come across a following document with the proof that interests me, unfortunately I'm not able to follow it.

[The proof is here.](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/graph/345_connectivity.pdf)

I completely don't get what's so contradictory about the last statement in Prosposition 4.3, namely

"Then $V(H) \cap V(K)=\{v\}$ the shortest path containing $e,f$ has length $k$, the shortest path containing $e,f'$ has length $<k$. Contradiction.

What's so contradictory about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $f'$ share the vertex $v$, and $v$ is the seperating vertex between $H$ and $K$. Consider the shortest path containing $e,f'$, starting with $e$ and ending with $f'$. Because $v$ is the seperating vertex, the path has to end with $vw$.  But then you can change the last part to $vu$ and get a path containing $e,f$ of the same length.

Comment: Thanks, that's so obvious I'm embarassed :P